# Explaining a definition of the pronoun

Tags: meaning, pronouns, definition

Could someone explain to me this part "used by itself" in the definition of a pronoun?

> **Pronoun**: a word that can function as a noun phrase used by itself and that
>   refers either to the participants in the discourse (e.g. I, you) or to
>   someone or something mentioned elsewhere in the discourse (e.g. she,
>   it, this).

Comment: As a learner: I think the author meant to underline the fact that a single term  (the pronoun) can be used as a noun phrase, you know a noun phrase can be composed of several nouns or adjectives.

Comment: Pronouns aren't *always* references to dialogue participants or things / people mentioned elsewhere in the conversation. Think about things like ***It's raining***, or ***I've got to go. It's late*** (where it makes no sense to ask ***What's raining**?* or ***What's late**?*).

Comment: Where is this definition taken from? Please provide a source when quoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Uesd by itself" here means that the pronoun alone, without any other words, functions as the entire noun phrase.

> **He** was born in 1960.

Here "He" is the grammatical subject, and stands in place of a noun or noun phrase such as "John Smith" or "The man who I met last night". A pronoun can also serve as the grammatical object, or in other grammatical role. But it always takes the place of a noun or a noun phrase.

> - Jane packed up the box and gave it to **him**. (indirect object)
> - John married **her**. (direct object)

Pronouns do not always refer to people or things mentioned in nearby text. Sometimes they are generic, and sometimes they serve as placeholders in set phrases.

> - It's late. (Implied "the time is late" or "the hour is late")
> - It's raining. ("It" here has no real antecedent or referent, even implied.)
> - It is a good idea to be honest. (It refers to the idea.)